# How to implement an Authentication endpoint using ADB2C

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0

I can't seem to find a proper answer to this common question.

How to implement in C# a Web API endpoint for authenticating, which means receiving username/password in request, contacting my ADB2C server by forwarding the credentials, get a bearer token and return it as a response?

I managed to have a working proof of concept by using a ROPC User flow, but that seems [bad practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) and furthermore I need the User flow to use an API Connector, which is not supported by ROPC.

Comment: ADB2C is based on OAuth, which means a third party is the responsible for authentication where user interaction is required on the third party authentication web page. You cannot implement a Web API endpoint to do this, unless you open a browser manipulate it using something like Puppeteer and get the token

Comment: @JesúsLópez thanks, ouch. Does that mean that any Web API that needs to implement an Authentication endpoint (seems very common to me, I've used one for every Web API I've interacted with, i.e. first authenticate by sending credentials to the Auth endpoint, then include the token received in every request to the API after that) cannot be based on OAuth for security?

Comment: I think authentication should be made in the client application then your client application will query your API thru HttpClient but before that your API should grant access to that client application for your client application to be able to acquire token and be able to request to API, so basically you have 2 App Registrations (client app and API)

Comment: I have implemented a web application that uses ADB2C. It has a SPA frontend and a Web API backend.  The frontend authenticates using @azure/msal-browser library to ADB2C, then sends the authentication token to every Web API end point.

Comment: @VincentDagpin Thanks. If I understand correctly, the client would need to 1. Acquire a bearer token from ADB2C (by sending a request to xyz.b2clogin.com or similar), then using the token when requesting my API (at myapi.com)? I wanted the client app to not necessarily know that my Web API is using ADB2C, and so would prefer that the Authentication endpoint is controlled on the same server as the whole API. It is surprising to me that this is not achievable with ADB2C...

Comment: @JesúsLópez I have implemented that also, with a front-end SPA it works great. However now I am developing a "pure" Web API with no front-end...hence the need to authenticate by using a (publicly exposed) API endpoint for that. I am really baffled that this is not possible with ADB2C O_o

Comment: @Bruno, the login web page can be customized in a way it looks like your brand. Even the domain can be changed

Comment: @JesúsLópez But my current Web API (to be secured) is aimed to be usable by a system (i.e. a C#  HttpClient used by my client), so I cannot rely on a browser window...

Comment: I think B2C is not the best choice to use in that scenario, because your scenario sounds more like B2B

Comment: Maybe you can do this, If you're in control with your C# HttpClient then you can create a new app registration that can be used for your client app, your client app doesnt need to login, you just need to acquire token by providing the clientId and secret of your client app so it can request to your API, that way you can also protect your client app with secret/certificate and also you can control who can only access your API

Answer (score 1):

- B2C is a global public resource with two endpoints /authorize and
  /token. As commented it uses Oauth and OpenID protocols.
- B2C is reponsible to serve bearer tokens to your users inside it in the /token endpoint.
- You need to implement your own User flow or custom policies workflow which will render views to your frontend through the /authorize endpoint.
- Best practice is to implement an Auth Code Flow unless you are trying a Device code flow (TV's). I understand you need to let your users login and register through this workflow. Check for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow
- Your front end will need some configuration normally using MSAL library for whatever language you are using like: TenantId, ClientId and so on (check documentation above).
- You can place a public API behind your B2C to handle custom claims and permissions, if you dont need so with both B2C endpoints you have enough.
- You will need to create a SPN (App Registration) so your frontend has access to your B2C (get the ClientId/applicationId from it) and redirectURI to configure your frontend.
- To create custom policies you can check this repo to start with your login/register workflows: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack
- Adding an API in front of your B2C is not a good practice.

Hope it helps a bit.